# How Does Fannkuch Work?

Tags: algorithm

I'm having trouble understanding the instructions of implementing Fannkuch.
Instructions: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Shootout/Fannkuch

After step "Count the number of flips, here 5.", I am lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, yes, that is not the greatest algorithm description :).

My interpretation is they want you to do the following:

```
fannkuch(n) {
 int maxFlips = 0, printCount = 0;
 foreach permutation p of [1..n] {
  maxFlips = max(maxFlips, flipCount(p));
  if (printCount++ < 30) printPermutation(p);
 }
 print(maxFlips);
}

flipCount(p) {
 int count = 0;
 while (p[0] != 1) {
  reverse(p, p + p[0]);
  count++;
 }
 return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I am understanding this now however I noticed that there appears to be a correct order of permutations that get printed. I'm trying to understand now why those specific 30 permutations are printed, and why in that order.

Comment: The specific permutation order doesn't really matter.  That specific order is listing the permutations in lexicographical order from 'smallest' to 'largest'.

That is generally how functions like next_permutation() in C++ would behave given a sorted list.  Interesting article on this -> http://marknelson.us/2002/03/01/next-permutation/.

Comment: So the list of 30 permutations is just the results of the function to generate the first permutations? They are not completely in lexicographical order. The fourth and fifth permutations are out of lexicographical order.

Comment: Whoops, you are totally right.  I only read the first few permutations.  It looks like they have a well defined permutation order they want you to use, which is given in C or Lisp in the PS file on the site.

A few of the given Haskell examples even have "this does not use the correct permutation order" :).

Answer (score -2):

See the [Benchmarks Game - Fannkuch](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=fannkuch&lang=all#about)

Requiring the first 30 permutations to be printed was just a simple way to limit the acceptable changes that could be made to the algorithm.